# Do doubles suffer from overflow?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, floating-point-precision, floating-point-exceptions

Is it possible to have an overflow (wrap around) with a double or a float? What will happen if the maximum (or minimum) value is reached on x86 or x64 hardware?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On an IEEE-754 compliant system, overflow results in a special "infinity" (or "minus infinity") value, beyond which any further increment will have no effect.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Floats go to `Inf` or `-Inf`