# In IEEE float implementation when an Overflow leads to INF, is it considered as undefined bahavior?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, undefined-behavior

It's all in the Title. For example if the addition of two floats results in INF, does it generate an undefined behavior? or is this avoided in IEEE float implementation?

Comment: Undefined behaviour seems to be the flavour of the day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When a float variable goes out of the float limits, what happens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588419/when-a-float-variable-goes-out-of-the-float-limits-what-happens)

Comment: @devnull I lol'd so hard. At least this question is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  There is no undefined behavior in IEEE-754 arithmetic.  The result is *defined* to be infinity for the example in question, and it is *defined* to set a flag indicating that overflow occurred.

The only room for undefined behavior is if the platform in question doesn't adhere to IEEE-754.  (C and C++ **do not** require that floating-point arithmetic follows IEEE-754)

Comment: Can you please give some examples of flags that indicate OVERFLOW?

Comment: The Overflow flag indicates overflow.  In most implementations, this flag is implemented as a bit in a hardware floating-point status register (x86, for instance, uses bit 3 of the x87 FPU status register, and bit 3 of the MXCSR register), but that specific realization is not required by the standard.