# Why "is_modulo" is false for double and float?

Tags: c++

I wrote some code to check if a type has a modulo representation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    cout << "Whether float objects have a modulo representation: "
         << numeric_limits<float>::is_modulo << endl;
    cout << "Whether double objects have a modulo representation: "
         << numeric_limits<double>::is_modulo << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Whether float objects have a modulo representation: 0
Whether double objects have a modulo representation: 0
```

But we can use `fmod()` (from `<math.h>`) to find modulo of `float` or `double`. So, why is `is_modulo` false if it is possible to find a modulo of a float or double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_modulo)

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_modulo` is **`true` for all arithmetic types T that handle overflows with modulo arithmetic**, that is, if the result of addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division of this type would fall outside the range [`min()`, `max()`], the value returned by such operation differs from the expected value by a multiple of `max()-min()+1`.

Overflow of floating point numbers [is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588419/when-a-float-variable-goes-out-of-the-float-limits-what-happens), therefore `std::numeric_limits::is_modulo` for `float` and `double` is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `fmod`. Arbitrary operations on a floating-point value are irrelevant.

Whether one has "a modulo representation" is like how `unsigned int`s automatically wrap-around.

Neither `float`s nor `double`s do that, and `is_modulo` is `false` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_modulo):

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_modulo` is *true* for all
>   arithmetic types T that *handle overflows with modulo arithmetic*, that
>   is, if the **result** of addition, subtraction, multiplication, or
>   division of this type would fall outside the range `[min(), max()]`, the
>   value returned by such operation differs from the expected value by a
>   multiple of `max()-min()+1`.

so it does not say about 'finding modulo' but how `a + b` will behave. Floating point arithmetics do not overflows as integer arithmetics can.